# Spring.NET using multiple PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers isn't working

Tags: .net, spring, properties, configuration-files

I'm trying to use two property placeholder configurers, with one of them for retrieving the values base64 decoded.  The problem I am having is that only one of them is loading properties into the name/value collection.  Which one is dependent on the order I place them in XML (and  I do set the first one to ignoreUnresolvable when switching them).

Here's what the config looks like:

```
  <object id="propertyConfigurer" type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>file://~Database.config</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="configSections">
      <list>
        <value>database</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
  </object>

  <object id="encodedPropertyConfigurer" type="MyProject.Config.EncodedPropertyConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>file://~Database_auth.config</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="configSections">
      <list>
        <value>database_auth</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
  </object>
```

I extend PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, overriding the virtual method like so:

```
public class EncodedPropertyConfigurer : PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
{
    protected override string ResolvePlaceholder(string placeholder, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection props)
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base.ResolvePlaceholder(placeholder, props)));            
    }
}
```

Again, based on the order I put them in the Web.config, only one of the files is loaded into the Name/Value collection.  As pasted, it would use encodedPropertyConfigurer (for example, I would see "username" and "password" in the collection, but not the connection string.  If I flip the order, I would see "connectionString" but not username or password.)
What did I do wrong?  The documentation says multiple PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer are supported, and only to be careful of the ignoreUnresolvable setting.
Note that I tested using both instances as the Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (instead of my extended class) and the SAME behavior occurred - only one is loaded into the list.

Answer (score 1):

Related to this: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6428

Specifying a different placeholder prefix/suffix for the other PPCs works, although is not ideal.  Like this:

```
<!--  DB Properties (non-encoded) file configurer -->
  <object name="propertyConfigurer" type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="configSections" value="database"/>
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
  </object>

  <!--  DB Properties (encoded) file configurer -->
  <object name="encodedPropertyConfigurer" type="MyProject.Config.EncodedPropertyConfigurer">
    <property name="configSections" value="database_auth"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="$[" />
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="]" />
  </object>
```

And then just make sure the ones that are to be retrieved from the second one are used with $[] instead of the default ${}.